# React and Redux Architecture

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have questions about React and Redux architecture.

Suppose you have normalized data

```
const user = [
  { userId: 1, name: 'Ian', groupId: 1 },
  { userId: 2, name: 'Tom', groupId: 2 }
]

const groups = [
  { groupId: 1, groupName: 'Facebook developers'},
  { groupId: 2, groupName: 'Google developers'}
]

const chat = {
  { userIdFrom: 1, message: 'Hello!', timestamp: 1324132332 },
}
```

What is the best practice to manipulate data such as `.map`, `.filter`, `.reduce`, `.forEach`, `.sort`, denormalization etc?

I create utils functions to handle huge data manipulation like `Utils.getChatsFromUsers` etc and invoked from `render` method on Component.

Is this my solution good practice to handle huge and many data manipulation in Component's `render` function?

Please give me your advise and insight.
Thanks!

Comment: I would find a way to minimize the data manipulation in my render method because the only thing it should be concerned with is displaying the UI. How often do you expect this data to change? Is it real-time updates, on user refresh, etc?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The data won't be changed often so I didn't use redux for this app yet. But when it comes to denormalize it and keep it, I was thinking of creating Redux and denormalize data on reducer function. Otherwise, denormalize it on UI component and update state of component which sounds messy for me...

Comment: If you're consuming normalized data, and just displaying it to the user, why do you need to denormalize it? It seems to me that you are creating a new data structure from several sources of normalized data. All you would need to do is transduce the data into whatever form you wish, save it in state,  or redux) and display it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not really a good practice to manipulate arrays inside the render method unless the array is the only thing being rendered, or if the array is the prop the will most likely change. You should manipulate them in the componentWillReceiveProps.

So, instead of having something like this:

```
render() {
    const { string1, string2, string3, array } = this.props;
    const mappedArray = array.map(element => <li>{element}</li>);
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{string1}</p>
        <p>{string3}</p>
        <p>{string3}</p>
        <ul>{mappedArray}</ul>
      </div>
  );
}
```

you should do something like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  // R is from ramda, but you can compare the arrays any way you want
  // even just comparing the array references if that's good enough for you
  if (R.equals(nextProps.array, this.props.array)) {
    this.mappedArray = array.map(element => <li>{element}</li>);
  }
}

render() {
    const { string1, string2, string3, array } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{string1}</p>
        <p>{string3}</p>
        <p>{string3}</p>
        <ul>{this.mappedArray}</ul>
      </div>
  );
}
```

This way you avoid having to recreate the mapped array every time the render method is called (which could happen from other props changing or the state being changed).

This topic is covered [here](https://codeburst.io/when-to-use-component-or-purecomponent-a60cfad01a81).